# Join Table variable with a Table - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This question might looks simple and repeated, Since I am beginner in SQL, I have stuck up with this problem.

I have created a table variable to store hour range in a 24 hr format. Here is the code

```
DECLARE @TIMERANGE TABLE ([TIME] NVARCHAR(MAX))

;with hrs (time)
AS
(
    SELECT 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT time+1
    FROM hrs WHERE time<23
)
INSERT INTO @TIMERANGE select 
RIGHT ('0000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, time), 4) + '-' + RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, time + 1), 4)     AS [TIME]
from hrs
```

output for this table is:

```
TIME
0000-0001
0001-0002
0002-0003
0003-0004
0004-0005
0005-0006
0006-0007
0007-0008
0008-0009
0009-0010
0010-0011
0011-0012
0012-0013
0013-0014
0014-0015
0015-0016
0016-0017
0017-0018
0018-0019
0019-0020
0020-0021
0021-0022
0022-0023
0023-0024
```

Condition is, I want to join this with my real table with a specific condition

```
Id    Date           Time        Score
 1    2008-01-01     00:05         15
 2    2008-01-01     00:15         20
 3    2008-01-02     10:15         05
 4    2008-01-02     11.00         55
```

I want to find the sum of score in specific time range, Eg, 00.15 will falls in Time range 0000-0001.

Desired output is:

```
Time Range   Score

0000-0001    25
........     ..
........     ..
```

Please Help

Comment: I might not be completely understanding your question, but is there a reason you aren't just calling `GROUP BY` with a `COUNT` on `DATEPART(HOUR, Time)`?

Comment: Some times there will be no record against specific time, say no records in time range 0002-0003. In such case I want to show them as null. When I use DATEPART, I am getting only the hour part of time, not the time range, If my understanding is true

Comment: The DATEPART() function is used to return a single part of a date/time, such as year, month, day, hour, minute, etc.

Comment: Change your timerange TR table so that it contains "start time" and "end time". Then you can join your real table T1 with: `T1.time between TR.start_time and TR.end_time`. Time and Date are BTW reserved words so you might want to replace the names of the columns with something more specific.

Comment: I need output in a single column Time range :( I have to use TIME here because even if there is no records in some time range, Have to show them as null

Comment: Doing a conversion like that will be super inefficient no matter what. If you have control over the in-memory table, why are you constrained to one column?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you can't handle the `NULL` values on the UI? Doing it in SQL just seems like it will be slower and a worse design decision.

Comment: It is a report, have to handle null in the back end. What I meant is there won't be any records at some time range, then I have to show them as zero

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping I understood the requirements.  I see why you did the CTE.  I've done that to support graphs so every hour in the day is represented, with or without resulting data.

I re factored the query to produce the following:

```
    declare @tmp TABLE (MyDate DATE, MyTime TIME,Score INT)
    INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES('2008-01-01','00:05',15),
    ('2008-01-01','00:15',20),
    ('2008-01-02','10:15',05),
    ('2008-01-02','11:00',55)
    SELECT SUM(Score) Score,datepart(hour,GETDATE()) TimeRange FROM @tmp Group By           datepart(hour,MyTime)
```

The result will show the SUM (or average or whatever you need) by Hour.  If you still need to graph the result THEN join back into your CTE on the Hour component of the time.

Hope this helps.